# Arduino TM35 Temperature Sensor Wrong

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, temperature

I am starting out trying to learn some C++ and embeded programming but i am having some real issues with my TM35 sensor.

[image: Read Out]

[image: readout]

It is worth noting my bedroom is not in the 50 degrees celsius, its mid 20's at the highest.

The Sensor is connected to the A0 Serial port, 5v and ground as it should, and i have checked its done the right way around with the middle leg of the sensor going to a0 and with the flat side facing you the left pin is going to 5v and right pin to ground.

Below is the code, it is not my code as im learning im just playing with other peoples code for now.

```
const byte tempPin = A0;
float calibration = 0.1039;
float temp; // Celcius
float volts;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReference(INTERNAL1V1); // use internal 1.1volt Aref
  // change INTERNAL to INTERNAL1V1 for a Mega
}

void loop() {
  temp = analogRead(tempPin) * calibration; // get temp
  volts = analogRead(tempPin);
  Serial.print("Volts: ");
  Serial.print(volts);
  Serial.print(", Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp, 1); // one decimal place resolution is all you get
  Serial.println("*C");

  delay(1000); // use a non-blocking delay when combined with other code
}
```

I have also tried this code too but same results.

```
float temp;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  temp = analogRead(A0);
  temp = temp * 0.48828125;
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");Serial.print(temp);Serial.print("*C");
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: How are you choosing this calibration value?

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=614660.0

Comment: If you know the true temperature of the room can't you derive your own calibration factor?

Comment: if i knew that, this would be easy, however the erratic nature of the readings is confusing.

Comment: updated with a second capture of some readings

Comment: Could be a hardware problem

Comment: im thinking that but before i order another to confirm i want to be sure.

Comment: I think you've got your `Volts` formula wrong. Shouldn't it be `milli_volts = analogRead(tempPin)*5000./1023.`?

Comment: Also, `analogReference(INTERNAL1V1)` sets _the value used as the top of the input range_ to 1.1V - but your sensor will output up to 2V. What if you try this instead:

`analogReference(INTERNAL2V56);` and `milli_volts = analogRead(tempPin)*2560./1023.;` ?

Comment: decided ill go buy another sensor, also found out what i was told is a TM35 is a LM35, i swapped the pin layout around for it yet no difference